# How to make an audio pop up?

Tags: javascript, html

I want my mp3 music file (3 secs) to play every-time my pop ups appear.

I have already search for some code but could not find any format or patterns.

The pop ups appear but without the 3 seconds music.

I've looked up for code patters or format but could not find any

```
const intervalID = window.setInterval(harvestSeason, 10000);

const harvestSeasonSound = document.getElementById("harvestingSeasonSound");

function harvestSeason() {
  alert("It's almost harvesting season!");

};
```

the pop up appears but without any sound.

Comment: `audioElement.src = 'your.mp3'; audioElement.play();`

Comment: @StackSlave has the solution, at no point in your code are you actually telling your code to play the sound, you're referencing it & saving it's value into a variable, but not starting the audio track.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple audio player. I used `setTimeout` to emulate your popups.

```js
function AudioOnly(audioElement){
  this.audio = audioElement || document.createElement('audio');
  this.play = function(src){
    if(src)this.audio.src = src;
    this.audio.play();
    return this;
  }
  this.pause = function(){
    this.audio.pause();
    return this;
  }
  this.stop = function(){
    this.audio.stop();
    return this;
  }
}
var ao = new AudioOnly;
setTimeout(function(){
  ao.play('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/Yodel_Sound_Effect.mp3');
}, 10);
setTimeout(function(){
  ao.play('https://freesound.org/data/previews/488/488614_6150892-lq.mp3');
}, 3000);
```